# SoapUI API - Setting TestCase property

Tags: properties, jython, soapui

I'm trying to use SoapUI API in jython (modifying SoapUILibrary for Robot Framework) and somehow i am not able to find any way to set property of a Property TestStep.

Setting project, global and system properties is easy using

SoapUITestCaseRunner.setProjectProperties()

```
from com.eviware.soapui.tools import (SoapUITestCaseRunner)
from com.eviware.soapui.tools import (SoapUIMockServiceRunner)

from robot.api import logger

class SoapUILibrary2:
    """ The main class of the library """

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '0.2'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__runner = None
        self.__mockrunner = None
        self._project_properties = []

    def soapui_project(self, prj):
        """ Initialize the runner and set the project string """
        self.__runner = SoapUITestCaseRunner()
        self.__runner.setProjectFile(prj)

    def soapui_suite(self, s):
        """ Set the suite string """
        self.__runner.setTestSuite(s)

    def soapui_case(self, c):
        """ Set the test case string """
        self.__runner.setTestCase(c)

    def soapui_set_project_property(self, *properties):
        """ Sets project properties for the current test run. (...)
        """
        for prop in properties:
            if len(prop.split('=')) == 2:
                self._project_properties.append(prop)
            else:
                logger.warn("Skipping property: '%s'. Properties must be specified as: key=value" % prop)
        try:
            self.__runner.setProjectProperties(self._project_properties)
        except AttributeError:
            logger.warn('No project set. Cannot set project properties.')
```

SoapUITestCaseRunner class does not contain any way to access testSteps...

I found some examples how to solve this issue in groovy, however is it possible to set such properties using SoapUI API?

EDIT:

Adding whole code of the library. It's made to be imported in robot framework and used as its keywords.

http://tny.cz/34882261

Answer (score 0):

In SOAPUI you can define properties for project, testCase and testSuite, it's also possible to generate a special type of testStep (Properties TestStep) but you can't define properties on a specific testStep (i.e on SOAP TestStep). You can see more info about [here](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html)

However you can use a properties from project, testCase or testSuite in your testSteps so i.e you can define a property in a project level and then use it in your testStep. I can't give more specific info because I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

EDIT:

I don't know the specific jython syntax but If you have the project file (as I see in your sample) you can access a specific testStep through `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject`, I give you a groovy script as example:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep

def prj = new WsdlProject(path_prj_file,null);
def tsuite = prj.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuiteName");
def tcase = tsuite.getTestCaseByName("TestCaseName");
def tstep = tcase.getTestStepByName("TestStep");
```

EDIT 2:

I download jython standalone version 2.5.3 and use soapui 5.0.0 and works for me:

**hw.py**

```
from com.eviware.soapui.tools import (SoapUITestCaseRunner)
from com.eviware.soapui.tools import (SoapUILoadTestRunner)
from com.eviware.soapui.tools import (SoapUIMockServiceRunner)

from com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl import (WsdlProject)
from com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl import (WsdlTestSuite)
from com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase import (WsdlTestCase)
from com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps import (WsdlTestRequestStep)

import thread

class SoapUI2:
    """ The main class of the library """

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '0.2'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__runner = None
        self.__mockrunner = None
        self._project_properties = []
        self.__prj = WsdlProject('C:\soapui_project.xml', None)
        self.__tsuite = self.__prj.getTestSuiteByName("myTestSuite")
        self.__tcase = self.__tsuite.getTestCaseByName("myTestCase")
        self.__tstep = self.__tcase.getTestStepByName("myTestStep")
        t = self.__tstep.getPropertyValue("Value")
        print "Works ok"


    def soapui_project(self, prj):
        """ Initialize the runner and set the project string """
        self.__runner = SoapUITestCaseRunner()
        self.__runner.setProjectFile(prj)

    def soapui_multiproject(self, prj):
        """ Initialize the runner and set the project string """
        self.__runner = SoapUILoadTestRunner()        
        self.__runner.setProjectFile(prj)

    def soapui_suite(self, s):
        """ Set the suite string """
        self.__runner.setTestSuite(s)

    def soapui_case(self, c):
        """ Set the test case string """
        self.__runner.setTestCase(c)

    def soapui_set_project_property(self, *properties):
        """ Sets project properties for the current test run.
        This assumes that you have already initialized the project via
        the `SoapUI Project` keyword.

        `properies` may contain multiple statements, and each must be specified as: key=value.

        This is useful to data drive your existing SoapUI tests via property expansion.
        For more information see: http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html

        Example:
        | SoapUI Project | My Project |
        | SoapUI Set Project Property | ServiceEndpoint=https://staging.company.com | # set a single property |
        | SoapUI Set Project Property | CustomProperty=foo | AnotherProperty=bar | # or set multiple properties |
        """
        for prop in properties:
            if len(prop.split('=')) == 2:
                self._project_properties.append(prop)
            else:
                logger.warn("Skipping property: '%s'. Properties must be specified as: key=value" % prop)
        try:
            self.__runner.setProjectProperties(self._project_properties)
        except AttributeError:
            logger.warn('No project set. Cannot set project properties.')



    def soapui_set_multiproject_threads(self, t):
        """ Sets number of threads to run in load test """
        self.__runner.setThreadCount(long(t))
        logger.info("Running with %s threads at once." % t)

    def soapui_run(self):
        """ Run the runner and report to Robot """
        logger.info("Running with the following project properties set: %s" % self._project_properties)
        if not self.__runner.run():
            raise AssertionError('FAIL: failed to run')

        if self.__runner == SoapUITestCaseRunner():
            n = self.__runner.getFailedTests().size()
            if n != 0:
                raise AssertionError('FAIL: ' + str(n) + ' tests failed')

    def soapui_start_mock_service(self, p, m):
        """ Runs a mock service """
        try:
            self.__mockrunner = SoapUIMockServiceRunner()
            self.__mockrunner.setProjectFile(p)
            self.__mockrunner.setMockService(m)
            self.__mockrunner.setBlock(False)
            self.__mockrunner.run()
        except Exception, e:
            raise AssertionError('FAIL: Error running the mock service ' + m + '. Reason: ' + str(e))

    def soapui_stop_mock_service(self):
        """ Stops the mock service """
        self.__mockrunner.stopAll()

    def soapui_set_step_property(self, s, p,v):
        testStep = self.__runner.testCase.getTestStepByName(s)
        testStep.setPropertyValue(p,v)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SoapUI2().__init__()
```

**cmd line execution:**

`java -classpath "jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar;C:\Programari\SoapUI-5.0.0\lib\*;C:\Programari\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\*" org.python.util.jython hw.py`

**execution result:**

`2014-05-27 12:43:09,058 [main] WARN  com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI - Could not find jfxrt.jar. Internal browser will be disabled.
12:43:09,589 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [C:\temp\ext] for external libraries
12:43:09,964 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Documents and Settings\aciffone\soapui-settings.xml]
12:43:09,995 INFO  [HttpClientSupport$Helper] Initializing KeyStore
12:43:11,682 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/C:/soapui_project.xml]
Works ok`

Hope this helps,

Comment: What i need is to modify properties in Properties TestStep, sorry for confusion. Edited.

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry but I don't know jython specific syntax, but I give you a groovy sample which I hope that will help you :)

Comment: Unfortunately got exception. And as java/programming newbie (or do not know SoapUI API well enough) do not understand a thing:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.config.impl.InterfaceConfigImpl cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.config.WsdlInterfaceConfig`

Comment: ClassCastException indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. Can you share your jython code which produces this exception?

Comment: Edited. Code under the link.

Comment: I can't reproduce you error, what soapui version are you using? I see that there is a bug in soapui 4.0.1 with jython 2.5.1 about this class cast, I'm using 4.6.4 you can try with this version.

Comment: I try with jython 2.5.3 and soapui 5.0.0 and it works, I edit again my answer if you want to check the details.

Comment: It still produced same error. It's probably caused by Robot Framework screwing up somewhere. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I remove the "from robot.api import logger" from your python script however I don't think that it's the error cause... anyway I hope that you will find the solution.